# Returning an alert message with a database response

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, alert

I am trying to show a message box from the controller when the index is returned, I have done the following which works for alerts where I do not insert a response message spat out by the database:

Are the quotes in the wrong place?!

```
"<script>alert('Unsuccessful. Try again.'" + response + " );</script>" ;
```

Edit:

I should say that I am assigning this to a ViewBag in the controller and then displaying in the View as `@Html.Raw(@ViewBag.Foo)`

Comment: Why is your script tag in quotes?

Comment: @Amy I am assigning it to a ViewBag.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Because to assign it to a viewbag in the controller I have to create a string... @Amy

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>alert('Unsuccessful. Try again.' + response  );</script> ;
```

Try that :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need quotes just assign response to gloabl variable then use following code

```
<script>alert('Unsuccessful. Try again.' + globalVarible  );</script> ;
```

Answer (score 0):

your single quote should come after `response`

```
"<script>alert('Unsuccessful. Try again." + response + "' );</script>";
```

you need to be certain that `response` does not have single quotes as well

Answer (score 0):

Creating the `script` tag in the controller and using `@Html.Raw()` is unnecessary. Instead, you should assign `response` to a `ViewBag` property like this:

```
ViewBag.Foo = response;
```

And then in your View,

```
<script>alert('Unsuccessful. Try again.' + '@ViewBag.Foo')</script>
```